# How do I get Perl's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel to create formulas with VLOOKUP?

Tags: perl, excel

I'm having difficulty with [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) and formulas that use `VLOOKUP`. The following test script populates a worksheet with some data and tries to create a `VLOOKUP` formula. When I open the resulting Excel file, the formula results are displayed as `#VALUE!`. If I manually edit any of the cells containing formulas (press F2 and then just ENTER without changing anything), I can get Excel to evaluate the formula properly. Any idea what going wrong?

For what it's worth, if I open the same file in OpenOffice, the formulas work fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $wb = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('foo.xls');
my $ws = $wb->add_worksheet;

for my $r (0 .. 9){
    for my $c (0 .. 4){
        $ws->write($r, $c, $r * 10 + $c);
    }
    $ws->write($r, 10, $r * 10);
    my $formula = sprintf('=VLOOKUP(K%s, A1:B10, 2, FALSE)', $r + 1);
    $ws->write( $r, 11, $formula );
    # $ws->write_formula( $r, 11, $formula ); # Does not help either.
}
```

Version info:

- Excel 2007 SP2.
- Spreadsheet::WriteExcel: tried both 2.25 and 2.37.

Comment: What version of `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` are you using?  Your code works fine in 2.25 using Excel on OSX.  Might just be your Excel install?

Comment: does explicitly calling write_formula instead of write work?

Comment: @ysth and @Jack M. Good ideas, but no luck. I edited the question with version info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am the author of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

This is a known error with the formula parser and certain formula types in WriteExcel. You can work around it using `store_formula()` and `repeat_formula()` as shown below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $wb = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('foo.xls');
my $ws = $wb->add_worksheet;

my $formula = $ws->store_formula('=VLOOKUP(K1, A1:B10, 2, FALSE)');

# Workaround for VLOOKUP bug in WriteExcel.
@$formula = map {s/_ref2d/_ref2dV/;$_} @$formula;

for my $r (0 .. 9){
    for my $c (0 .. 4){
        $ws->write($r, $c, $r * 10 + $c);
    }
    $ws->write($r, 10, $r * 10);

    $ws->repeat_formula( $r, 11, $formula, undef, qr/^K1$/, 'K' . ($r +1) );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the workaround? I'm using WriteExcel in Ruby - https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel and facing the same issue. I would like to know what happens in the workaround so that I can code it in Ruby. Thanks

Comment: figured that the code is doing a search and replace within the array and used it to good effect to solve my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I'm maintainer of writeexcel rubygem.
for example, ruby code is below.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'writeexcel'

wb = WriteExcel.new('fooruby.xls')
ws = wb.add_worksheet

formula = ws.store_formula('=VLOOKUP(K1, A1:B10, 2, FALSE)')

# Workaround for VLOOKUP bug in WriteExcel.
formula.map! {|f| f.sub(/_ref2d/, '_ref2dV') }

(0..9).each do |row|
  (0..4).each { |col| ws.write(row, col, row * 10 + col) }
  ws.write(row, 10, row * 10)
  ws.repeat_formula(row, 11, formula, nil, /^K1$/, "K#{row+1}" )
end

wb.close
```